# How to introduce Redis just for caching no CRUD

Tags: redis, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jedis

I am planning to implement a caching layer in my application using Redis. right now the application is fetching huge-sized data from DB whenever the user initiates certain plan load. this plan load behind the scene, triggers few heavyweight data accesses and orchestrate all calls in final results.

Data access is happening through JPA Repository right now to access my Oracle DB. when I introduced redis layer, it's not initiating the cache in first access, rather the application tried to fetch data from the empty cache.

My questions are

1. would my design work, since I want to keep the CRUD operations as is in JPA repositories. I just want to introduce redis for caching, no crud operations.
2. I have a huge amount of data(probably 2 GB) that should sit in the cache layer. how much can max data redis hold?

Answer (score 1):

> My questions are
>
> 1. would my design work, since I want to keep the CRUD operations as is in JPA repositories. I just want to introduce redis for caching, no crud operations.

It is gonna work however you will have main problem cache invalidation.
When you do CRUD operation your redis cache still will have old data and you will have inconsistency. The general way of using redis as cache is setting ttl(Time-To-live) for each key. But you can solve such inconsistency by introducing trigger which erases key in redis if you do any CRUD operation.

Depend on your workload you can meet case when you have low cache hit rate.
For example, if you rarely access to keys in the cache then all of them will be expired until next access. Frankly cache will not work effectively in this case. It could be avoided by warming cache or using redis not as cache but as second storage with replicating data.

> 2. I have a huge amount of data(probably 2 GB) that should sit in the cache layer. how much can max data redis hold?

Redis is extremely efficient and limited by your physical resources(RAM) and by size for key and for data stored by key, it is 512Mb.

You have to account that redis can fragment data among virtual memory than your source 2Gb of data represented by keys and data for it can occupy 3GB RAM.